# return to specific page in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to return to a specific page after I edit a record using Django "UpdateView", however this page url needs an argument passed to it as well (see urls.py below). I am pretty sure I need to use "get_absolute_url", which works when I am just redirecting to an unfiltered page, but can't seem to get the syntax to redirect to a filtered page.

**Models.py**

```
class DefaultDMLSProcessParams(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    customerTag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    processNotes = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,default = "") 

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.defaultParamDescrip)

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        #self.object.pk? pass this below somehow?
        return reverse('Default_Listview',)
```

**views.py**

```
class defaultUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = models.DefaultDMLSProcessParams
    fields = ['processNotes','customerTag']
    template_name = 'default_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:device>', DefaultsListView.as_view(), name='Default_Listview'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the parameter by **`args`** argument of **`reverse()`** function

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # self.object.pk? pass this below somehow?
    return reverse('Default_Listview', args=[self.id, ])
```

You could find more example in the [Official Django doc .](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)